# Page rendering using leaves view

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using the [Leaves project](https://github.com/brow/leaves/) to move from one pdf page to another it is working fine. Now the page curl is from left to right and from right to left like a note book. I need to curl it from top to bottom and bottom to top.  Does anyone know the methods to do it, or any other templates to do this?

Comment: [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];

Comment: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp -->
    A transition that curls a view up from the bottom.

UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown -->
    A transition that curls a view down from the top.

[UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp)

Comment: What's the leaves view template? Googling it brings up this post!

Comment: Have you considered just using `UIPageViewController`?  It has a `navigationOrientation` property which you can just set to ` UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing leaves view is hard-coded to be left-to-right.  You can create a hard-coded top-to-bottom version easily enough, but there may well be more robust generic solutions.

However, if you definitely must use leaves, you can rewrite its source to suit.  The solution below hard-codes for vertical motion.  If you need horizontal and vertical options, you will have more work do do.

---

## Display

### setUpLayers

Reverse the axes in every call to `CGPointMake`.  This fixes up the gradients that display the shadows.

Also change `topPage.contentsGravity = kCAGravityLeft;` to `topPage.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottom;` and `topPageReverseImage.contentsGravity = kCAGravityRight;` to `topPageReverseImage.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTop;`.  This is a subtle change that makes sure incoming pages are displayed with the correct edges.

### setLayerFrames

Most of the geometry changes happen here.  The original code oddly uses view bounds in some places and layer bounds in others.  I duplicated those, but it would be good to understand if the distinction is meaningful before using this code in production.

```
- (void) setLayerFrames {
    topPage.frame = CGRectMake(self.layer.bounds.origin.x, 
                               self.layer.bounds.origin.y, 
                               self.bounds.size.width,
                               leafEdge * self.layer.bounds.size.height);
    topPageReverse.frame = CGRectMake(self.layer.bounds.origin.x,
                                      self.layer.bounds.origin.y + (2*leafEdge-1) * self.layer.bounds.size.height,
                                      self.bounds.size.width,
                                      (1-leafEdge) * self.layer.bounds.size.height);
    bottomPage.frame = self.layer.bounds;
    topPageShadow.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                     topPageReverse.frame.origin.y - 40,
                                     bottomPage.bounds.size.width,
                                     40);
    topPageReverseImage.frame = topPageReverse.bounds;
    topPageReverseImage.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, -1, 1);
    topPageReverseOverlay.frame = topPageReverse.bounds;
    topPageReverseShading.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                             topPageReverse.bounds.size.height - 50,
                                             topPageReverse.bounds.size.width,
                                             50 + 1);
    bottomPageShadow.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                        leafEdge * self.bounds.size.height,
                                        bottomPage.bounds.size.width,
                                        40);
    topPageOverlay.frame = topPage.bounds;
}
```

---

## Interaction

### updateTargetRects

Where this calculates `nextPageRect` and `prevPageRect`, put them on the bottom and top instead of the right and left.

### touchesMoved:withEvent:

Change `self.leafEdge = touchPoint.x / self.bounds.size.width;` to `self.leafEdge = touchPoint.y / self.bounds.size.height;`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the UIPageViewController from Apple instead of Leaves http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

This gives you exactly the curl they use in iBooks for example, so a lot more beautiful (more realistic) matrix of the curled view.

Just make all your note sheets a View and give the views the UIPageViewController
It also has various options where the spine is located and other stuff

To make a curl up you could either use 
`[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];` like bala mentioned or instantiate another UIPageViewController that is responsible for up and downwards transitions. 
If you want to really go into the view and maybe switch with this through multiple items i would just use 2 uipageviewcontrollers so one horizontal and one vertical

Answer (score 2):

this method

```
 SampleViewController *sampleView = [[[SampleViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [sampleView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentModalViewController:sampleView animated:YES];
```

as in [this](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/) tutorial may be helpful